# What is a C++ container with a "contains" operation?

Tags: c++, insert, integer, containers, contains

I want to use a structure in which I insert integers, and then can ask

```
if (container.contains(3)) { /**/ }
```

There has to be something like this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<int> myVec;
myVec.push_back(3);
if (std::find(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), 3) != myVec.end())
{
    // do your stuff
}
```

You can even make a little helper function:

```
template <class T>
bool contains(const std::vector<T> &vec, const T &value)
{
    return std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value) != vec.end();
}
```

Here is how you would use it:

```
if (contains(myVec, 3)) { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: @Nemo: The OP never asked for a fast-execution method, but only for a working method. I offered a general solution to a general problem. If the OP asks for a specific problem where speed is important, then an other solution would be better. Picking a `std::set` right away just to save a linear-time search implies other design consequences and I would consider this as premature optimization (when in fact the search could not even be in a performance bottleneck). Premature optimization is the root of all evil. A different solution to a problem is not worth a down-vote, IMO.

Comment: @Nemo: A correct linear-time solution is fine unless measurement proves it is a significant bottleneck.

Comment: Linear time is the best you can do if you can't use a sorted list or a hash table for some reason (eg. you want to preserve order of insertion.)

Comment: What we all should know: Linear iteration over collections linear in memory (as vector if homogeneous) is (if repeated) fast as lightning! Keep shades close by!

Answer (score 11):

Simple algorithm:

```
template <typename Container>
bool contains(Container const& c, typename Container::const_reference v) {
  return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), v) != c.end();
}
```

You can customize it for more efficient search on some known containers:

```
template <typename Key, typename Cmp, typename Alloc>
bool contains(std::set<Key,Cmp,Alloc> const& s, Key const& k) {
  return s.find(k) != s.end();
}

template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Cmp, typename Alloc>
bool contains(std::map<Key,Value,Cmp,Alloc> const& m, Key const& k) {
  return m.find(k) != m.end();
}
```

And this way you obtain a single algorithm that performs the search on any container type, and is special cased to be faster on those containers which are ordered.

Answer (score 5):

`find` on an unsorted vector is O(n).

[`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) supports O(log n) insertions and lookups and is a good choice.

`std::tr1::unordered_set` provides a similar interface but supports near-constant-time lookups.  It is the best choice if you have TR1 (or C++0x) and do not need to enumerate the elements in order.

Comment: For small n's, an unsorted vector is perfectly fine, perhaps even faster.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the find_first_of method from the algorithms library. (or binary search, or anything along those lines)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_first_of/

Comment: std::find_first_of searches for subsequences in a larger sequence, but 'contains(3)' has only a single scalar, with no begin/end range. So std::find is a better fit here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a C++ standard container, due to its design, the containers themselves do not necessarily have "contains", but you can always use the find algorithm.

You should choose your container according to the characteristics of your dataset and the access "workload".

For a good reference of the containers and algorithms on the C++ standard library check http://www.cplusplus.com

[Containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/), [Algorithms](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/)

If as it seems, your data is made of unique items, for which you want to associate a value, you probably will be well served by the map container. If all you care about is "membership", then set is a better choice.