# How to check if a string is in a list of strings?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, input, cin

In Python, doing `if a in b` is really easy, and I'm wondering if there's an equivalent in C++.

Specifically, I want to make a list of strings and check if an input is in that list.

```
std::string myinput;
std::string mylist[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
std::cin >> myinput;
// if myinput is included in mylist
// do other stuff here
```

How do I check using an `if` whether the input `myinput` is included in string `mylist`?

Comment: Assuming you mylist would have only unique values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194797/what-is-a-c-container-with-a-contains-operation

Answer (score 21):

You could use `std::find`:

```
std::string myinput;
std::vector<std::string> mylist{"a", "b", "c"};

std::cin >> myinput;
if (std::find(std::begin(mylist), std::end(mylist), myinput) != std::end(mylist))
    // myinput is included in mylist.
```

This works fine with only three strings, but if you're going to have many more, you'd probably be better off with an `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` instead.

```
std::set<std::string> myset;
// put "a", "b", and "c" into the set here

std::cin >> myinput;
if (myset.find(myinput) != myset.end())
    // myinput is included in myset.
```

Comment: +1: insertion in to a set wouldn't be a O(1) or O(n) though. So it depends what is really required (fast insertion / fast search)

Comment: @Chubsdad: Insertion in a set would be O(log n) in the usual case. At least in a typical case, you'd expect to search more than insert anyway. Of course, if you use `unordered_set`, you can expect the insertions to be O(1) as well.

Comment: Add header file `<algorithm>`

Answer (score 3):

Use [std::find, std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithms

```
  string myinput;
  string mylist[]={"a", "b", "c"};

  std::string *begin = mylist;
  std::string *end = mylist + 3;

  if (std::find(begin, end, "b") != end)
  {
    std::cout << "find" << std::endl;
  }
```

Or use C++11 `std::array` with `std::begin()`, `std::end()`

```
std::array<std::string, 3> mylist = { "a", "b", "c" };

if (std::find(std::begin(mylist), std::end(mylist), "b") != std::end(mylist))
{
  cout << "find" << endl;
}
```

Or Lambda:

```
if (std::find_if(std::begin(mylist), std::end(mylist),
     [](const std::string& s){ return s == "b";}) != std::end(mylist))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `std::count`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>  // std::count
#include <vector>

//using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> ans = {"a", "b", "c", "a"};
    std::cout << count(ans.begin(), ans.end(), "a") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

if the number `> 0`, it means the string is in strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
std::size_t listsize = sizeof mylist / sizeof mylist[0];
if (std::find(mylist, mylist + listsize, myinput) != mylist + listsize) {
    //found
}
```

If you know the size of the list beforehand, I suggest `std::array` which exposes iterators and a `size()` function, as well as a few other benefits over built-in arrays. Note that this is C++11 only (the C++03 near equivalent is `std::vector`), and also with C++11 comes `std::begin` and `std::end`, which reduce it to this:

```
if (std::find(std::begin(mylist), std::end(mylist), myinput) != std::end(mylist))
```

It's fairly easy to make your own for built-in arrays in C++03 as well, but with a standard container that exposes `begin()` and `end()` members, this shouldn't be too necessary, though it is more versatile.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, True, I'll add that in with the std::array note.

Comment: Thanks, although I was hoping for something a little simpler, I guess I'll have to try to understand how to use that.

Comment: @Sumyjkl: it's as simple as in Python, the only difference is the syntax but what is happening is really the same. Using C++ without using STL is like using python without its included API

Comment: @Sumyjkl, It's just the initial concept to get over. `find()` searches through the range you specify (more easily noted with the begin and end functions) and returns the position (an iterator) at which it's found, or the end of the range if it is not. That's why you have to compare the result with the ending position you pass in. The whole `sizeof` business divides the total size of the array by the size of one element, giving the number of elements, but as mentioned, the standard containers expose an easy `size()` member, though it's not too useful in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with C++ don't hesitate in using the STL library:

```
  string mylist[]={"a", "b", "c"};
  vector<string> myvector(mylist, mylist + sizeof(mylist)/sizeof(mylist[0])); 

  if (find(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), mystring) != myvector.end()) {
    ..
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use find as others suggested, or you can use a for loop(easierfor beginners):

```
for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size() ; i ++){
        if (myinput == mylist[i]){
               //Do Stuff
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (find(mylist, &mylist[3], myinput) != &mylist[3])
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string myinput;
    string mylist[]={"a", "b", "c"};
    if (cin >> myinput && 
        std::find(std::begin(mylist), std::end(mylist), myinput) == std::end(mylist))
    {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```